# how to show that row equivalence is an equivalence relation?

Tags: linear-algebra, equivalence-relations

I know that the properties of equivalence relations include reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity. But how do I apply this to matrices?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: elementary row operations (and corresponding matrices) are invertible.